# APP_VERSION is not defined Ionic Prod build for a component

Tags: angular, ionic3, uploadcare

I am using the lazy loading approach in Ionic 3. I tried to use your plugin named “ngx-uploadcare-widget” but it said the UCwidget is not defined and please import it into the page. After several hours of debugging, I found that it had to be moved to a shared component folder and then import it individually in pages, by doing this all the errors were fixed and the app was working fine on the browser and on debug build.

But when I did `ionic cordova build --release --prod` the app seems to be hung in the sense it was showing me blank white screen, since we cant debug prod I was left clueless on what is happening, later in one of the Ionic forms I learned that we can add a call back function to `this.navCtrl.setRoot(‘HomePage’)`. When I did that and generated a build I was able to see an error saying `(ReferenceError APP_VERSION is not defined for Uploadcare)` and now again I have no idea on what to do :(. If anyone here has encountered a similar issue or understands this problem request you to please help me in fixing this as I have been stuck here since a month and not sure what to do.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Got this resolved by the Uploadcare team! (https://github.com/uploadcare/ngx-uploadcare-widget/issues)